# How to take a site offline using Drush?

Tags: drush

How can I take a site offline using Drush?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Drupal 8: `drush sset system.maintenance_mode TRUE`

Drupal 7: `drush vset maintenance_mode 1`

Drupal 6: `drush vset site_offline 1`

Comment: If you are using drush-5.x, you may now simply use "drush vset maintenance_mode 1".  Drush will rewrite maintenance_mode to site_offline for Drupal 6. (This feature is newer than the above answer.)

Comment: Be sure to clear caches (`drush cc all`) after changing this variable.

Comment: Drupal 8: `drush state-set system.maintenance_mode 1` (I don't like drush's aliases)

Comment: Drupal 8 should also be 1 or 0 - **not** true or false. `drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1`

Answer (score 15):

First you should cd into the correct directory so that you are within the Drupal directory. If you are using a multi site installation cd into the correct sites/sitename directory or specify the correct -l setting

In Drupal 6 only this command is actually required:

```
$ drush vset --yes site_offline 1;
```

Also in Drupal 6 you can use the following commands if you wish to specify a message to show to the users of the site whilst it is down.

```
$ drush vset --yes site_offline_message "This site is being maintained";
$ drush vset --yes site_offline 1;
```

In Drupal 7 use following command to put the site into maintenance mode:

```
$ drush vset --yes maintenance_mode 1;
```

To set an a specific message use:

```
$ drush variable-set --yes maintenance_mode_message "This site is being maintained"
```

It could be necessary to clear caches that the changes of these variables take effect:

```
$ drush cc all
```

Comment: This does not work if the variable does not already exist. You're missing the --always-set parameter.

Comment: The variable gets created by the installer though. Go install a fresh drupal and look in the variable table.

Comment: Upvoted due to including the site_offline_message part. I believe the Drupal 7 equivalent of site_offline_message is maintenance_mode_message?

Comment: You don't need to clear the cache, variable_set() does that for you: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x

Comment: variable_set only clears two caches. cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');

Answer (score 3):

To do this with Drupal 8 and Drush 8.x use the [`state-set` command](http://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/state/state-set/):

`drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1`

At first, I assumed this would be something I would set with `drush config-set system.maintenance`, however the only keys in that configuration are `message` (the message displayed when maintenance mode is enabled) and `langcode` (the language code for said message).

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by a variable, site_offline.

```
$ drush vset --always-set site_offline 1
```

You could also set the offline message this way.

```
$ drush vset --always-set site_offline_message 'Please try again later!'
```

Comment: This would bring the site back up if it is down for maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Of course it should be set to 1, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

From Drupal 6 use:

```
drush vset site_offline 1
```

To take it out of maintenance:

```
drush vset site_offline 0
drush cc all
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 and onward:

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1
drush cr
```

Important to not forget clearing cache afterward, if you are running a devOps system.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 9 onwards:

Enable Maintenance Mode

```
drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 1 --input-format=integer
```

Disable Maintenance Mode

```
drush state:set system.maintenance_mode 0 --input-format=integer
```

After running this, do not forget to clear caches:

```
drush cr
```

Thank you.