# Drupal maintenance over several environments

Tags: 7, database, updating, maintenance-mode

I have a production environment for a Drupal 7 site.

This environment is replicated to a staging environment, which we use for testing updates to modules and drupal core (same major version).

We would like to sync this environment with the production one everytime we want to test an update, and then replicate the changes.

The way I envision the process is the following:

1. rsync everything from production to staging, getting the updated content from production and crushing any staging changes, deleting any files from staging that do not exist in production
2. replicate database from production to staging, so we can test pages and functionalities on production content replica
3. perform updates on the staging environment
4. rsync from staging to production, not deleting in production content that might not exist in staging

Question #1: Do updates make changes to the database? Or are these file only changes? Will rsync be enough to get the production in sync with staging after the updates?

Question #2: Is there a better, more robust way to achieve this?

Question #3: Should I set the site into maintenance mode while doing #4? Can this be done by setting maintenance mode programatically in a config file, rsync that file and everything else, then reset the maintenance mode and rsync that file? (I am looking to build a script to automate this)

Comment: Generally, yes, this will work like you envision in #1 and #3, but some files shouldn't be persisted from an environment. I think that the question is too broad and opinionated for an answer because it depends heavily on how the infrastructure is setup. Things you may be overlooking: database back port and  sanitization (possible with drush), settings files, running database updates or other drush scripts as part of your deployment process.

Comment: thanks @mradcliffe this kind of defeats the purpose of the script. There's no point in using rsync to do this if updates require database changes, unless I would do some sort of diff in the database. I can keep step 1 of the process, but there's no point in automating the rest.

Comment: I disagree. rsync is just a file transport tool and perfectly fine to use to deploy build artifacts from one environment to the other, and can be used together with drush to perform "database updates" (or any type of drush script) automatically. I would recommend thinking of non-production databases as non-persistent, temporal state. Those exist as a way to test the build artifact, whether in a linear fashion or a review-based one. I've worked with schema compare before and it just ends up with messy permanent environments in my opinion.

Comment: There's also content staging and deploying content, which gets complicated. Again, depending on how infrastructure, content work flow makes sense, but if the core (or contrib.) content work flow doesn't seem to please content reviewers working in production and they insist on being able to review things in a non-production environment, then there are several other models for deployment,

Comment: @mradcliffe I am not sure exactly with what you disagree, but my concern is: What point is there to using rsync in step 3 if I still need to run the updates directly on the production environment, so database upgrades are performed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You deploy code so you *can* run the database updates in production (?)

Comment: sorry @mradcliffe but I don't understand your comment. I do the updates in a staging environment, which means updating files and database. Then I rsync this to production. What is the point of rsyncing this to production, if only the files are sent to the production environment, but not the database updates? I would have to re-run the update process in production directly to make the database updates, meaning that files would be reinstalled, hence redoing the work done by rsync. Either I am not understanding your suggestion, or the process does not make sense as it won't do what's needed.

Comment: I find the point of testing a deployment is to test the entire deployment - code, database updates, feature reverts, etc...so that the risk of a failure in production is reduced by mitigating any failures in staging first, then re-running and testing the deployment. But this is why your question is too broad because you didn't provide the details about your infrastructure, deployment process, etc... And thus you got a broad answer that really doesn't get at what you're trying to do.

Comment: @mradcliffe thanks for the clarification. I have the staging environment for testing purposes, and for that reason I like the ability to test the update procedure. On that point, I agree with you. I was just wondering if, after testing in staging, one could simply mirror that to production. That does not seem to be possible, at least in a simple, straightforward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question #1: Do updates make changes to the database? Or are these file only changes? Will rsync be enough to get the production in sync with staging after the updates?

Updates will most likely do changes to the database. That's where most of the fun comes in when doing updates :D

> Question #2: Is there a better, more robust way to achieve this?

Syncing production to the staging system every now and then is a good idea, I'm not sure if you need it everytime you want to test something.
I'm assuming your deployments go through that staging system as well, so your content there will already be something you can test with. As far as I know there is no way to be 100% sure you're not going to kill your production environment. That's why you back up the database and the code and everything, before doing any change to production.

> Question #3: Should I set the site into maintenance mode while doing #4? Can this be done by setting maintenance mode programatically in a config file, rsync that file and everything else, then reset the maintenance mode and rsync that file? (I am looking to build a script to automate this)

You can set the maintenance mode using drush. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32/47426 To disable maintenance mode, run the same command with 0/FALSE instead of 1/TRUE. And don't forget about the cache clear.

Comment: thanks, this kind of defeats the purpose of the script. There's no point in using rsync to do this if updates require database changes, unless I would do some sort of diff in the database. I can keep step 1 of the process, but there's no point in automating the rest.